# Does Rails 3.2 have way to automatically create an empty child (nested) record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

My model Foo `has_one :bar` and Bar `belongs_to :foo`, and Foo `accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar`

When I create an instance of Foo (programatically, not via a form), I want to automatically create a blank child instance of Bar.

AFAIK I have to do it explicitly:

```
f = Foo.new(bar_attributes: {})
... do stuff ...
f.save
```

Is there an additional declaration in the model of Foo that says not only to accept nested attributes for bar, but to create one no matter what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a callback in foo.rb

```
before_validation :init_foo, on: [ :create ]

def init_foo
   self.build_bar
end
```

This will create a new instance of bar linked to foo each time you create a new foo object.

Comment: Foo has *one* Bar. One-to-one associations use a [special build syntax](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference). Edited.